# Problem with installing react-navigation version4

Tags: reactjs, react-native, installation, react-navigation

I installed react-navigation by this command:

```
npm install react-navigation
```

After that, i tried to install its dependencies

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

i got following  error.
How can i fix this?

[image: react-navigation error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your react native version? And did you try couple of times. Sometime I got an error while installing new packages but when try again it works.

**I have installed react navigation version 4 for many react native versions above 0.60.0. It perfectly worked. Please try again and post the react native version you are using.**

Comment: My react native version is "0.61.5", I've already tried several times but issue is still persisting, Please keep in your mind that the plugin itself has been installed without any problem, My problem is that i can't install its dependencies.

Comment: I think the issue with the git. Please make sure you have git installed and properly in your PATH.

Comment: Please see this https://forums.expo.io/t/error-when-i-try-to-run-npm-install-in-my-project-folder/20873 .I think this should be the same issue.

Comment: Thanks buddy, issue was about git as you said, It's solved now.